# DocuSign API create envelope in XML with Recipient Custom Fields

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I am trying to use recipient custom fields in xml. I have tested the solution in JSON and it works, but it needs to work in XML for the client's system.

I can find no online examples of such a payload and what the translated value should be. I have tried a few different versions, with none of them working. Please see below for details.

**Working JSON version:**

```
"recipients": {

            "signers": [

               {

              "email": "person@email.com",

              "name": "ExternalDocuSign",

              "roleName": "External Signer 1",

              "routingOrder": "1",

              "recipientId": "External Signer 1",

              "customFields": [ "Rolename: External Signer 1" ], - Recipient Custom Field

              },
```

However, it does not work in XML. To be clear, everything else but recipient custom fields works as expected.

**XML version with Recipient Custom Fields not working:**

```
<recipients>

<signers>

<signer>

 <recipientId>External Signer 1</recipientId>

<email>person@email.com</email>

<name>ExternalDocuSign</name>

 <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>

<roleName>External Signer 1</roleName>

<CustomFields><CustomField>Rolename: External Signer 1</CustomFields></CustomFields> - One example of a failed attempt

</signer>

</signers>

</recipients>
```

Comment: did you try customFields instead of CustomFields? make it camelCase?

Answer (score 0):

Note the DocuSign eSignature REST API uses camelCase and not PascalCase, so it should be:

```
<recipients>

<signers>

<signer>

 <recipientId>External Signer 1</recipientId>

<email>person@email.com</email>

<name>ExternalDocuSign</name>

 <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>

<roleName>External Signer 1</roleName>

<customFields><customField>Rolename: External Signer 1</customFields></customFields> - One example of a failed attempt

</signer>

</signers>

</recipients>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for replying. I have tried that method also, without much luck.

<customFields><customField>Rolename: External Signer 1</customFields></customFields>

I switched PascalCase in one of my different attempts.

Comment: are you trying to use a template? what are these custom fields? I see role names, and these are usually for templates

Comment: Its a composite template I am using. The recipient custom field is to bridge a gap DocuSign connect has presented. 

We need to send to a third party system the recipient's role name, to define if its a external or internal signer.  However, DocuSign Connect XML does not include that data point, the JSON version does though. To overcome this, recipient custom fields were added to the composite template to send over this extra data. I tested and in the DocuSign connect XML, the recipient custom field data is present. 

Everything else is working in the code. Just recipient custom fields.

Comment: There is a character limit on this site. Just to add some extra detail. 

In JSON my solution works, in XML, it does not. There is no error given, the envelope is still created with all the other data points and configuration correct. But the recipient custom fields are not created for the given envelope. 

I use DocuSign connect to test if the payload has the expected data, to simulate my use case.

Comment: Why can't you use JSON?

Comment: I wish we could. There is a lot of middleware owned by other teams that make up an integrated solution. Sadly, they all use XML and cannot switch to JSON due to a number of reasons. 

In addition DocuSign should be able to support XML. Without a piece of online documentation that confirms it cannot support Recipient Custom fields, it will be hard to justify such an expensive change or new design approach.

Comment: Do you use the REST API or SOAP API?

Comment: I am using REST API

Comment: I'm wondering if a workaround of making a second API call just to add the custom fields may work